# How can I use values from a csv file, to loop my python script?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a problem. I use python 2.7.13 to gather some data from a web page.
I try to gather the data from multiply articles.

I use the folowing script to gather the data that I want to have.

```
    import urllib2        
    i=0
    line = open("artikelen.csv", "r").readlines()[i]

    url = 'http://shop.niemann-frey.de/cshop/product.html?SID='
    SID = '1cfbf44f2a062d40b1d8dd3fd9c434ff'
    curl = '&art_nr='
    artnr = line

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url+SID+curl+artnr)
    webContent = response.read()


    for item in webContent.split("</title></head>"):
        if "<html><head><title>" in item:
            artikel = item [ item.find("<html><head><title>")+len("<html><head><title>") : ]
            print "artikelnummer is: " + artikel

    import csv
    with open(artikel + '.csv', 'w') as fw:
        writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')

    f = open(artikel+'.csv','wb')    

    for item in webContent.split("&mode=thumb&dbname=bilder"):
        if "https://shop.niemann-frey.de/cshop/lib/progs/getmedia.php?id=" in item:
            nummer = item [ item.find("https://shop.niemann-frey.de/cshop/lib/progs/getmedia.php?id=")+len("https://shop.niemann-frey.de/cshop/lib/progs/getmedia.php?id=") : ]
            print nummer

        f.write(nummer+";")
        f.close
    i+=1
```

The list I use looks more or less like this

> Artikelnummer:
> 1B000928
> 1B001279
> 1B001114
> 1B001271
> etc.

I want to use this values as "artnr" and I want to preform my script for all the values in the list. How can I manage this?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as:

```
with open("artikelen.csv", "r") as csv:
    for artnr in csv:
        # your code here
```